# Placing multiple images on a 3D surface

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

If I was to place a texture on the surface of a 3D object, for example a cube, I could use the vertices of that cube to describe the placement of this texture.

But what if I want to place multiple separate images on the same flat surface? Or suppose it is just one image, but I don't want it to appear at the edges of the surface, where the vertices are, but rather somewhere small and in the middle of the surface. I want the actual images to be chosen and placed dynamically at runtime, otherwise I could condense them offline as a single texture.

**I have an approach but I want to seek advice as to whether there is a better method, or if this is perfectly acceptable**:

My guess is to create multiple separate 2D quads (with depth of 0), each with a texture associated with them and placed on them (they could of course be a texture atlas with different texture coordinates).

Then, I transform these quads such that they appear to be on the surface of a 3D object, such as a cube. Of course I'd have to maintain a matrix hierarchy so these quads are transformed appropriately whenever the cube is transformed, such that they appear to be attached to the cube.

While this isn't necessarily hard, I am new to texturing and would like to know if this is a normal practice for something like this.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not normal practice at all, so it's hard to say what "normal practice" is for something people don't usually do. Textures are generally built to be used as-is. If you need something on part of a wall, then your texture artist would actually put that in the wall's texture or your modeller would put a polygon that is embedded in the wall, which the texture artist adds the special thing to.

Comment: @NicolBolas In my researching this, I found that what I'm asking is not much different than rendering differing glyphs from a bitmap font onto a surface, where each glyph is a different image taken from the same texture. One popular implementation I found was in fact doing essentially what I've suggested above (except with glyph images in a texture rather than other types of images), so I think it's not too uncommon.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns Like a 3D decal on a surface than a collage of textures making up a surface?

Comment: unless "decal" is a specific term, how does it vary from a texture on a quad as I've proposed? @JamesEldridge

Comment: @SebbyJohanns It doesn't vary much, decals are a gaming term done by projection from user input to a surface. Z fighting can be an issue, increasing the frustum near distance when rendering them is a common trick.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: If you decide to "paste" your transformed quads on top of the cube, watch out for *depth fighting*.

Comment: @RahulBanerjee thanks, good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what if I want to place multiple separate images on the same flat surface?

Use multiple textures, maybe each with its own set of textuer coordinates. Your OpenGL implementation will offer you a number of textuer units. Each of them can supply a different texture.

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE_0 + i);
glBindTexture(…);
glUniform1i(texturesampler[i], i); // texturesampler[i] contains the sampler uniform location of the bound program.
```

> Or suppose it is just one image, but I don't want it to appear at the edges of the surface, where the vertices are, but rather somewhere small and in the middle of the surface.

That's where GL_CLAMP… texture wrap modes get their use.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_{S,T,R}, GL_CLAMP[_TO_{EDGE,BORDER}]);
```

With those you specify texture coordinates at the vertices to be outside the [0, 1] interval, but instead of repeating the image will show only one time, with only the edge pixels repeated. If you make the edge pixels transparent, it's as if there was no image there.

Comment: In my researching this, I found that what I'm asking is not much different than rendering differing glyphs from a bitmap font onto a surface, where each glyph is a different image taken from the same texture. One popular implementation I found was in fact doing essentially what I've suggested above (except with glyph images in a texture rather than other types of images).

Answer (score 1):

You could try rendering a scene and saving that as a texture then use that texture on the surface.

Check out [glCopyTexImage2D()](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glCopyTexImage2D.xml) or [glCopyTexSubImage2D()](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glCopyTexSubImage2D.xml).

Or perhaps try using frame buffer objects.

Comment: interesting functions, though not sure they'd be wiser in this particular example, they do look like useful techniques for other needs. if I used them here, I'd still have to do what I was doing, but then also incur the overhead of copying the texture every time images were updated; as I'm planning to update images often this might be inelegant

Comment: Another way would be to recreate the texture by combining the data of other texture images. You would have to keep the image data buffered in memory though, probably a lot of overhead as well. I think your current approach is probably the best.

Comment: thanks; i'm hoping some of the big guns on here will appear to offer some insight as well. as i've learned there's almost always multiple approaches to accomplishing something in OpenGL or graphics in general.

Comment: @JamesEldridge: Could you please make a tiny edit to your answer? I just realized what OP asked for and your advice is in fact sound, but I prematurely downvoted it. I can't change my vote without you making a small edit, though. Just insert a space, change a comma or such.

Comment: @datenwolf I made an edit but don't worry about the downvote :-), my answer is pretty short.

Comment: @datenwolf i've never had any problems removing a downvote that I clicked accidentally, and removing it without any changes from the answerer

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: After a certain amount of time, votes are locked and can be changed only after an edit was made to the answer.